# Is there any way to reach this chest off the bridge in the Howling Plateau?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm exploring the Howling Plateau and have found a seemingly inaccessible chest, just to the side of a wooden bridge over a small gorge:

[image: unreachable loot]

I'd dismiss it as a cute background decoration except that it glows just like real chests, which seems oddly pronounced for a background decoration. Plus, it feels really close :)

I've tried looking around for levers etc. but found nothing. Is there any way to reach it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my game, on the other side of the chest as where you were standing (if you consider where you are the bottom left, it would be on the on the top right).  Was a hill with a man  who started one of the mini-quest things when you talked to him.

He would try and raise the chest while about 3 waves of enemies came and attacked you.  After killing all of them, the chest would be raised and you had access to the items inside.

I'm not sure if you haven't explored that part yet, or if the random map generation just made the chest appear without the appropriate quest to get it.  But try walking around to the other side of that chest.

Comment: There was indeed a hill on the other side, with a lever on it. No quest - I guess it's a random thing. Still, I got the chest :) thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I just found a lever which raises the chest (glowing white in my case) without any event. See below:

[image: Path to lever which raises chest]